# Ouput To CSV Format

Tags: hpcc-ecl

Is there a way to output to csv while keeping the original schema of the dataset? Output to csv will make the original dataset under the "line" column, and will introduce two additional columns. Usually, I can manually remove the columns and do some cleaning. But the file I am working on is too big and the only solution I have is to read line by line and re-parse the strings to keep only data in the "line" column and reconstruct the csv file locally.

Also, will ECL support parquet format output in the future?

I have mentioned a potential solution above, but it is a lot of work. I wonder if there is anything that is already built-in as this seems to be a common problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're talking about writing a CSV file with a single text field called "line" and you're concerned that the result looks like this in your ECL IDE:
[image: data image]

So, this is my result of writing a single "line" field to a CSV file, and I can see where you might think there are two additional fields in the output -- but there is only one field that is written to the disk file.

The "##" column is just a record number for display.

The "fileposition" column simply displays the relative byte position of each record written to the disk file.

If you look at the file on disk, you will only find the "line" field content (with each record terminated by a LF).

As far as PARQUET support goes, that has been requested ([JIRA Ticket for PARQUET support](https://track.hpccsystems.com/browse/HPCC-20992)) and will hopefully show up sometime in the near future.

HTH,

Richard

Comment: What I did was that I downloaded the file to disk from HPCC. The __fileposition__ column persists in the downloaded csv. Probably I should spray it to a landing zone, as I remember then only the content under "line" will be written as a csv. Thank you.

Comment: You "downloaded the file to disk from HPCC" how? I'd like to try to duplicate this issue myself, but I need to know exactly how you did that.

Answer (score 0):

To OUTPUT to a CSV file and maintain your field information ("schema"), use the following syntax:

```
OUTPUT(recordset,,filename,CSV(HEADING));
```

The file in ECL Watch will now have your RECORD in the ECL tab. You can copy and paste that record into an ECL workunit and define a new DATASET with the record like this:

```
ds := DATASET(filenamw,recordfromECLWatch,CSV(HEADING(1)));
OUTPUT(ds);
```

That will preserve your field information (schema)

Regards,

Bob